# Question about a definition in topology

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a continuum (a compact connected metric space), then $$\text{Span}(X) =\sup
_{Z}
\inf_{(x,y)∈Z}d(x, y)$$
where $Z$ ranges over all (non-empty) continua $Z \subseteq X × X$ with $π_1(Z) = π_2(Z)$.

That is the definition.

My question: Is $\text{Span}(X)=0$ equivalent to $Z\cap \Delta\neq\varnothing$ for every (non-empty) continuum $Z \subseteq X × X$ with $π_1(Z) = π_2(Z)$?

($\Delta$ is the diagonal in $X\times X$)

Comment: I'd say that the span is 0 iff $Z=\Delta$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux for every $Z$? but that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. $Z$ is compact and $d$ is continuous, so it attains its minimum. Hence, the infimum is $0$ iff $Z$ intersects the diagonal. And so the span is $0$ iff every admissible $Z$ intersects the diagonal.